# How to concat list column to string column?

Tags: python

I have DF below.
I want to concat the list to string with new delimiter, what should I do?

| Name | Group |
| --- | --- |
| A, B, C | P1 |
| D, E, F, G | P2 |

I tried attached code, however,that code is not work in dataframe.

```
df['new'] = " & ".join(["Name = "+i for i in df['Name'].split(",")])
```

How can I get result like this?

| Name | Group | new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A, B, C | P1 | name == A & name == B & name == C |
| D, E, F, G | P2 | name == D & name == E & name == F & name == G |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just use the built-in pandas methods of the `str` module

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[['A', 'B', 'C'], 'P1'], [['D', 'E', 'F'], 'P2']], columns=['Name', 'Group'])

df['new'] = 'name == ' + df.Name.str.join(' & name == ')
```

Result:

```
        Name Group                                new
0  [A, B, C]    P1  name == A & name == B & name == C
1  [D, E, F]    P2  name == D & name == E & name == F
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex replacement approach here:

```py
df["new"] = df["Name"].str.replace(r'([^\s,]+),?\s*', r'name == \1 & ', regex=True)
                      .str.replace(r' & $', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_new_str(name):
    return " & ".join(["Name = " + i for i in name.split(",")])

df["new"] = df["Name"].apply(make_new_str)
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

is this what ur looking for:

````
df['new'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: f"name == '{x}'").str.cat(sep=' & ')```
````